# How to setup procmail to send all incoming mail to two, three or more scripts and leave a copy in mailbox?

Tags: linux, email, sh, procmail

How can I force .procmailrc for each incoming email:

1. leave this email in my mailbox as if nothing happened.
2. Give mail to script1.sh through stdin
3. Give mail to script2.sh through stdin
4. Give mail to script3.sh through stdin
5. Give mail to script4.sh through stdin
   and so on

how can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a bunch of non-delivering pipe actions

```
:0 c
|script1.sh

:0 c
|script2.sh

:0 c
|script3.sh
```

etc. When it falls through all the recipes without having delivered it will deliver to the system standard inbox.